# How to set animation time in a jQuery function with a "start" function inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to set the `slideToggle` time, but with a `start` function added, and if I set the time as usual, the page ignore the instruction.

```
jQuery('.mega-menu-toggle').on('click touch', function(){
    jQuery('.mega-menu').fadeToggle({
        start: function() {
            jQuery(this).css({
                display: 'flex'
            })
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

I tried to add the time in milliseconds before the `fadeToggle` closing bracket, but the browser ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When providing a settings object to `fadeToggle()` the duration value should be set in a property on the object:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.mega-menu-toggle').on('click touch', function() {
    $('.mega-menu').fadeToggle({
      duration: 2000, // add the duration here
      start: function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'flex');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

More information is available in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/#fadeToggle-options)

Note the use of the `$` alias in the document.ready handler arguments. This means you can use the `$` variable within that scope and reduce the verbosity of your code.